# How to jump to tab if trying to open already opened file in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm opening new tabs using command

```
:tabnew path/to/file
```

Is it possible to force Vim to jump to already opened tab with file,
if I'm trying to open file which is already opened?

Comment: I'd say this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Ok, next time I'll post such kind of question there.

Comment: Same for buffers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392784/vim-drop-for-buffer-jump-to-window-if-buffer-is-already-open-with-tab-autoco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the `:drop` command. It helps. Related infos:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_a_file_or_jump_to_it_if_already_open
- http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:drop

Comment: Thank you!
Must recompile with GUI option enabled.

Comment: Amazing! And `tab drop path` works as expected. Is there a `:buffer` analogue? And why do we need GUI for that?