# Vim :drop for :buffer - jump to window if buffer is already open with tab autocomplete

Tags: vim

[How to jump to tab if trying to open already opened file in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065711/how-to-jump-to-tab-if-trying-to-open-already-opened-file-in-vim) has introduced me to the `:drop` command, which is analogous to `:edit` but focuses on an existing window if there is a buffer open there with the same path instead of taking up the current window.

Is there a command analogous to `:drop` such that when I try to tab complete, instead of listing files in the current directory like `:drop`, searches in my open buffers like `:buffer` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `:sbuffer`. It works like `:buffer` except that it tries to jump to the first window displaying the desired buffer, defaulting to opening it in a new window otherwise. Its behavior is governed by the `switchbuf` option.

```
:help :sbuffer
:help 'switchbuf'
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `:set switchbuf += useopen` and `:tab sbuffer file` does what I wanted.

Comment: Good answer to OP’s question, but to be precise, `:sbuffer` does not work like `:buffer`: unlike `:buffer`, it will split the current window if it does not find its target in another window, and will also do so when its target is the current buffer (a no-op with `:buffer`).

Comment: @kopischke, all that is explained in `:help :sbuffer`.

Comment: @romainl yup, but your answer states that “It works like :buffer except that it tries to jump to the first window displaying the desired buffer before opening it in a new window”, which is factually incorrect, even if you link to the correct documentation. Maybe amend that sentence?